# Why does Siri need to know "which John?" for a reminder or calendar event?

Tags: ios, calendar, siri

Me to Siri: "add to my calendar Tuesday noon meeting with John"

Siri: "which John?"

...and then you can't proceed without picking a contact from the list. I'm afraid Siri is going to send a calendar invite or something to whichever contact I pick. I try to avoid using names now, or use funny names I know aren't in my contacts. Why does Siri need to know "which John"? Just add it to my calendar!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because why Apple does or doesn't do something is considered off-topic according to [help/on-topic].

Comment: What if I rephrase as "how do I disable…?"

Comment: @fsb This question is on-topic, it's a perfectly objective question asking why Siri needs to know something from the user, not why Apple made a certain decision.

Comment: I disagree @grgarside because the question goes to why Siri was programmed the way it was.  You're free to disagree and not vote to close the question, I'm ok with that.  Even the answer you gave doesn't actually answer the OPs question (the way it's currently written).  If the question was rewritten, as proposed, to focus on how to disable the feature, I feel that would be on-topic and a better question.  As long as the OP is happy with the answer, that's the important thing :-).

Answer (score 1):

Siri can add attendees to calendar events. When creating an event, saying ‘with John’ will add John as an attendee to the event, shown in the event attendees section in the Calendar app later. If you have multiple Johns, it'll ask which one you mean so as to not get it wrong. There isn't a way to disable this functionality as it's part of Siri's calendar functions.

Comment: Thanks. Is any kind of message sent to the contact?

Comment: what were the results of your test? :-)